# GPU Rendering Profile - Accurate?

Tags: android, rendering

I'm looking at the "GPU Rendering Profile" option in Android Developer Settings, which is fantastic (in it's concept), and with that option turned on, what strikes me as odd is that it often crosses the 60fps threshold even on simplest screens (like text editor, or even that developer settings list). The reason why it's odd to me, is that I have Samsung Galaxy S4 (i9500 to be exact - Jelly Bean 4.3), so it certainly doesn't look right, that such a powerful machine has trouble in achieving min of 60fps all the time at those simplest of screens.

Second reason why it looks odd, is that at least from what it looks, the part that makes it cross the threshold is the "Swap buffers" part, which (at least from Guy and Chet's talk) should be the quickest one. Over here, though, sometimes it's the largest part, and on some rare occasions it goes over the roof altogether. I've put links to the screenshots I made, so that it's better visualized.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/23242740/Screenshot_2014-01-05-13-53-33.png
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/23242740/Screenshot_2014-01-05-13-52-28.png
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/23242740/Screenshot_2014-01-05-13-53-17.png

All that happened while scrolling this developer's list. Has any of you maybe got the same issue in the past, and found the answer? Or maybe it's simply a bug?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html), the meaning of the bars is:

- blue: time spent creating drawing commands
- orange: time spent issuing the commands
- yellow: time spent waiting for the commands to complete

This means that you're issuing and drawing the command quickly enough, but sometimes waiting quite a while for completion.

What else is running? Could you enable CPU diagnostics (Settings > More > Developer Options > Show CPU Usage)? Perhaps there are other things (deamons, interrupt servicing etc) going on that could be interrupting the render process?